# Where are these missing options in menuconfig?

Tags: 13.04

I'm following ["How to assign devices with VT-d in KVM"](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/How_to_assign_devices_with_VT-d_in_KVM) and am trying to modify the Kernel config as it suggests.
But after going to `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.x.x-x` and running `make menuconfig` I can't find the following options:

```
"Bus options (PCI etc.)" -> "**Support for DMA Remapping Devices**" 
"Bus options (PCI etc.)" -> "**Enable DMA Remapping Devices**"
"Bus options (PCI etc.)" -> "**PCI Stub driver**"
```

They're just missing in menu options. Where can I find them?

Where to find CONFIG_X86 || CONFIG_IA64_GENERIC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These options depend on what version of kernel you are using and what dependencies
need to be turned on to become available these are described here:

- [DMAR](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/DMAR.html)
- [DMAR_DEFAULT_ON](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/DMAR_DEFAULT_ON.html)
- [PCI_STUB](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/PCI_STUB.html)

Comment: None of the above were found in my menuconfig, enabled them by going to `Device Drive→IOMMU` Hardware Support